# What is the best practice of handling time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I am using R for some statistical analysis of time series. I have tried Googling around, but I can't seem to find any definitive answers. Can any one who knows more please point me in the right direction?

Example:

Let's say I want to do a linear regression of two time series. The time series contain daily data, but there might be gaps here and there so the time series are not regular. Naturally I only want to compare data points where both time series have data. This is what I do currently to read the csv files into a data frame:

```
library(zoo)
apples <- read.csv('/Data/apples.csv', as.is=TRUE)
oranges <- read.csv('/Data/oranges.csv', as.is=TRUE)
apples$date <- as.Date(apples$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
oranges$date <- as.Date(oranges$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
zapples <- zoo(apples$close,apples$date)
zoranges <- zoo(oranges$close,oranges$date)
zdata <- merge(zapples, zoranges, all=FALSE)
data <- as.data.frame(zdata)
```

Is there a slicker way of doing this?

Also, how can I slice the data, e.g., select the entries in `data` with dates within a certain period?

Comment: The code is not quite right, and we don't have your csv files... maybe some dummy data?

Comment: I fixed the typos in the code. But I can't really see the point in dummy data. Just take any random data and put it in two column csv file and name one column date and the other close.

Comment: The reason is so that your question is not regarded as being of low quality and so that responders can easily run the code and multiple responders all run it using the same input.  Since this is something you can do yourself without knowing the answer to the question its generally regarded as your responsibility to provide this.

Comment: True. But since I asked for best practices (I didn't have any particular issue to deal with, I just wanted to know if there was a more straight forward way of achieving the same outcome), I didn't really think it was needed. Anyone who are used to working with time series in R would be able to get the gist of the code and then add his $0.02. Thanks for your answers nevertheless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something along these lines. This assumes that the dates are in column 1.  The dyn package can be used to transform `lm`, `glm` and many similar regression type functions to ones that accept zoo series.  Write `dyn$lm` in place of `lm` as shown:

```
library(dyn) # also loads zoo
fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
zapples <- read.zoo('apples.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = fmt)
zoranges <- read.zoo('oranges.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = fmt)
zdata <- merge(zapples, zoranges)
dyn$lm(..whatever.., zdata)
```

You don't need `all = FALSE` since `lm` will ignore rows with NAs under the default setting of its `na.action` argument.

The `window.zoo` function can be used to slice data.

Depending on what you want to do you might also want to look at the xts and quantmod packages.

Comment: I had no idea about the dyn package, very nice indeed.

Answer (score 6):

Why did you convert both data frames to `zoo` then merge and convert back to data frame? If you want a data frame, just run this line after your `read.csv()`.

```
data <- merge(apples, oranges, by = "date")
```

And here's how to subset.

```
subset(data, date < slicemax & date > slicemin)
```